# Generating Java Map or Property trees from flat name value pairs

Tags: java

There are have been numerous times where I have wanted a library that given some simple key value properties creates a tree of maps (and or lists) (a map containing maps.. think Java JSON) and or retrieves and sets values on an existing tree of maps.

An Example (property order is important):

```
a.b = "b"
a.c.d = 1
a.e.f[0] = "blah"
```

The above would be parsed into `Map<String,?>` where `a` is Map and `c` is a key in `a` with the value of a `Map` contains key of `d` with the value 1... etc.

A way to visualize this is as a JSON tree:

```
{ 
    "a" : 
    {
        "b" : "b",
        "c" : 
        {
            "d" : 1
        },
        "e" :
        {
            "f" :
            ["blah"]
        }
    }
}
```

I have ran into this many times of needing a simple object path like language and general expression languages will not work as the collections are not automatically created.

Consequently I have written my own simple split on `.` and recursively create maps but I am hoping that perhaps there is a well tested library that allows Java Object manipuluation/creation with out the overhead of a general purpose or turing complete expression language (ie Groovy and EL would be overkill).

I know that Spring has a DataBinder which does something analogous but it only works on POJOs and will not work on a general Map (this is because it needs to know how to convert the data which is not an issue here).

Here is another example of someone trying to do something similar albeit with Jackson: http://pastebin.com/F4feRr8y

Comment: I'm assuming that actually using JSON or YAML is not an option?

Comment: Its not. I'm basically taking a flat representation, expanding it, and then overlaying it on top of hierarchical one.